# Having trouble installing/uninstalling MONGODB

Tags: mongodb, installation, uninstallation

I am trying to install MONGODB, followed a bunch of tutorials and haven't had luck. Prior to this, when I typed mongo in the terminal, it would say it wasn't found. However I stumbled upon https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/unable-to-connect-to-mongo-shell-error-connecting-to-127-0-0-1-27017-caused-by-connection-refused-connect-src-mongo-shell-mongo-js13/89945/2 and copied

```
>mongo "mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-00-jxeqq.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-jxeqq.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-jxeqq.mongodb.net:27017/100YWeatherSmall?replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0" --authenticationDatabase admin --ssl --username m001-student --password m001-mongodb-basics
```

into my terminal. I want to restart fresh and get rid of everything related to mongo. However, even after following the instructions from https://www.mongodb.com/basics/uninstall-mongodb for mac, I can't seem to restart fresh. I seem to get

```
MongoDB shell version v5.0.9
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

My problem is that I am having trouble installing MongoDB and ended up blindly copying something. Now I can't seem to go back to the original message where after I type mongo, it would give the message saying it wasn't found. Instead, I get the message that I mentioned above. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: You write, you tried to **install MongoDB locally**, however your connections string attempts to connect to Mongo Atlas, i.e. **MongoDB cloud service** which naturally does not require any installation (apart from the mongo shell, which is a stand-alone .exe)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try these commands to repair and restart your mongodb server:

**1) Remove .lock file**

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
```

**2) repair the mongodb**

```
mongod -–repair
```

**3) start the mongod server**

```
sudo service mongod start
```

**4) start the mongo client**

```
mongo
```

Comment: I tried running the first line and it says "rm: /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock: No such file or directory". I'm not sure what to do now.